# Power BI report integration in asp.net mvc application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0, powerbi

Can you please let me know how to integrate Power BI report in Asp.Net MVC application ?

Application Details : Asp.Net MVC4 Hosted on Windows Server.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post your question on [softwarerecs](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com)

Comment: i dont know why this was marked down - this is a legit question

Answer (score 6):

refer to this:
https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-developer-embed-sample-app-owns-data/

Where the app owns the data and clients/users do not need Power Bi/MSFT credentials to view the data.